# An unpleasant adjective for each of the five senses

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a negative adjective to match each of the five classical senses. Each word should be short, simple, well known, the sort of word that would appeal or be known to children, and preferentially end in *-y* in order to form a nice set.

- hearing - it sounds *noisy*
- sight - it looks *ugly*
- smell - it smells *smelly*
- taste - it tastes *yucky*
- touch - it feels *yucky*

I'm looking for two words to replace *yucky* for taste and touch.

I've thought of *slimy* and *dirty* for touch, but I can't think of anything for taste, i.e. the opposite of *tasty* or *yummy*. The words should immediately or overwhelmingly evoke the sense it is linked to. That's why I don't like *yucky*; it's too generic.

Each word should work by itself: *it is **noisy*** (obviously hearing, discounting poor fashion sense); *it is **ugly*** (obviously sight), etc.

Suggestions?

Comment: This should be five different questions.

Comment: @TusharRaj No, only two. I've already got the other three words.

Comment: Oh. In that case, may I recommend `nasty` and `mucky`?

Comment: touch -- icky..

Comment: Touch can be so many different things: slimy, scratchy, itchy, etc.

Comment: "Gross" doesn't end in y but would be good for taste. I'd replace "smelly" with "stinky." Also, why are you trying to replace "yucky" for taste? I think that's the quintessential toddler word for something that tastes bad.

Comment: I'd say "nasty" for taste.  I don't think there's a good one for touch since I can't think of any really unpleasant tactile sensations apart from actual pain:  yes, you could cut yourself, or burn yourself, or suffer some sort of pain or damage from touching various things, but that doesn't really fit the question I think, since none of the other things are (presumably) **harmful**.  Can anyone think of a non-harmful but very unpleasant "touch" sensation?  Slime I suppose, or something that feels like poo.  But they're too specific to use.

Comment: Textbook case of the matter discussed in [Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity?cb=1).

Comment: How do you intend to use these creepy words?

Comment: Something could have both a 'foul' taste and a 'foul' smell... I feel like anything that tasted bad would also smell bad.

Comment: @YosefBaskin They will actually be used to describe software. We already have a huge list of "code smells", the code can be ugly (formatted badly) and variable and function names can be noisy, e.g. `thing_doer`. Both words are simply noise as they provide no relevant information. I'm going to write a blog article about this and want to extend the concept to all five senses.

Comment: honestly, I wouldn't link "yucky" to anything but taste. "icky" would be the touch equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

For taste, from [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unpalatable):

> **unpalatable**
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> Not pleasant to taste.

Nothing comes to mind for touch besides texture-specific words. "[Grimy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grimy)", "[slimy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slimy)", and "[chalky](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/chalky)" are all words I would use to describe textures that are personally repulsive in the right context. Touch-related words typically describe unique textures; their connotation often depends on the context and the reader/listener. Consequently, the negative feeling of the word depends on what you are describing and the context you are describing it in. Adverbial qualifiers ("overwhelmingly", "awfully", etc.) may be added to change the effect of the adjective.

If you really want a texture-neutral negative adjective for touch, I would stick to describing something as an "unpleasant texture" or something to that effect.

Comment: _Each word should be short, simple, well known, the sort of word that would appeal or be known to children, and preferentially end in -y in order to form a nice set._ How does _unpalatable_ qualify?